# Display float value w/o scientific notation

Tags: php, floating-point

When i make the following multiplication in PHP:

```
$ret = 1.0 * 0.000000001;
```

i get the result: 1.0E-9

I want to convert this result into the normal decimal notation, how can i do this?

`sprintf('%f',$ret)` doesn't work, it returns `0.000000`. Overflow?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> `sprintf('%f',$ret)` doesn't work, it returns `0.000000`. Overflow?

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) works, however you miss some point here.

`0.000000` is not overflow. It's just that `sprintf` for the `%f` modifier uses 6 digits per default. Also please take care that `%f` is locale aware, `%F` is probably better suited.

You might want to use more digits, e.g. let's say 4 000 000 (four million):

```
$ php -r "printf('%.4000000F', 1*0.000000001);"

Notice: printf(): Requested precision of 4000000 digits was truncated to PHP maximum of 53 digits in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
    0.0001     319080   1. {main}() Command line code:0
    0.0001     319200   2. printf() Command line code:1

0.00000000100000000000000006228159145777985641889706869
```

As this example shows, there is not only a common value (6 digits) but also a maximum (probably depended on the computer system PHP executes on), here truncated to 53 digits in my case as the warning shows.

Because of your question I'd say you want to display:

```
0.000000001
```

Which are nine digits, so you need to write it that way:

```
sprintf('%.9F',$ret)
```

However, you might want to do this:

```
rtrim(sprintf('%.20F', $ret), '0');
```

which will remove zeroes from the right afterwards:

```
0.000000001
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: you're da boss. been looking for this all over the internet.

Comment: After I found this answer I spend some time for research and this one is the best answer out there. You can freely use it guys.

Comment: Using `rtrim` on top of `sprintf` works like a charm.

Comment: `rtrim(sprintf('%.20F', $ret), '0')` will return `0.` if `$ret` is zero. 


Fix it like this: 
    `abs($x) < 1e-20 ? '0' : rtrim(sprintf('%.20f', $x), '0');`

Answer (score 7):

You need to add *precision specifier* (how many decimal digits should be displayed for floating-point numbers). Something like this:

```
echo sprintf('%.10f',$ret);  // 0.0000000010
```

If you have no idea what number you should specify, just give it a big number and combine it with `rtrim()`.

```
echo rtrim(sprintf('%.20f', $ret), '0');  // 0.000000001
```

The code above will strip any `0`'s from the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the use [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) for more accuracy when you are calculating with decimal numbers. That makes sure that you actually get the results you want.

To print what you want, you should specify the precision and use `%.9f`, since it defaults to displaying 6 decimal numbers. That makes it something like this (just like bsdnoobz already said):

```
sprintf('%.9f',$ret);
```

Comment: The problem is i get all this numbers from a database with various precisions.

Comment: Still, when you're working with floating point numbers, results may be different from what you expect. If precision is required, use BCMath. If you don't care whether there's a .000000001 (or something like that) added somewhere, you're fine using floats.

Answer (score 3):

To align to your system's settings and limitations, you could use `serialize_precision` to get the most accurate result possible.

```
echo rtrim(sprintf('%.'.ini_get('serialize_precision').'f', $ret));
```

I do not recommend using the non-locale aware `%F` since your question only makes sense for display purposes. Respecting locale makes for a better UX.