# Force to display regular decimal number

Tags: php, time, numbers, decimal, microtime

I'm running a benchmark test of doing nothing so the results is pretty fast.

Here is my code:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
//Do Nothing...
$time = microtime(true) - $time_start;

echo 'Took '.$time.' seconds<br>';
```

The problem is when I try to echo the results I'm getting this:

```
Took 1.3828277587891E-5 seconds
```

I'm expecting to get a regular decimal number like:

```
Took 0.000000008231 seconds
```

Is it possible to force php to display it as regular decimal number ?

Comment: PHP will switch to using scientific format based on the precision setting in your ini file: eithe rmodify that setting, or use [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to force non-scientific format display

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display float value w/o scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916675/display-float-value-w-o-scientific-notation)

Comment: similar question with good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917464/19905

Comment: Yep, I got the answer in that post! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your big numbers, then try this:

```
  //$i = gmp_init( $time ); // i think you need that only if you want convert a string to an int/flaot
  echo gmp_strval( $time );
```

gmp_strval PHP > 4.0.4 / PHP 5.

Mor infos http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php

Comment: Looks very interesting but... Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_init() in ...

Comment: I assume it's my PHP version but I will test it on higher version... :) Answer accepted! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `printf` or `sprintf` function. Here's a sample from http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
<?php
$n =  43951789;
$u = -43951789;
$c = 65; // ASCII 65 is 'A'

// notice the double %%, this prints a literal '%' character
printf("%%b = '%b'\n", $n); // binary representation
printf("%%c = '%c'\n", $c); // print the ascii character, same as chr() function
printf("%%d = '%d'\n", $n); // standard integer representation
printf("%%e = '%e'\n", $n); // scientific notation
printf("%%u = '%u'\n", $n); // unsigned integer representation of a positive integer
printf("%%u = '%u'\n", $u); // unsigned integer representation of a negative integer
printf("%%f = '%f'\n", $n); // floating point representation
printf("%%o = '%o'\n", $n); // octal representation
printf("%%s = '%s'\n", $n); // string representation
printf("%%x = '%x'\n", $n); // hexadecimal representation (lower-case)
printf("%%X = '%X'\n", $n); // hexadecimal representation (upper-case)

printf("%%+d = '%+d'\n", $n); // sign specifier on a positive integer
printf("%%+d = '%+d'\n", $u); // sign specifier on a negative integer
```

for your example, you can use -for instance- :

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
//Do Nothing...
$time = microtime(true) - $time_start;

echo 'Took '.sprintf("%f",$time).' seconds<br>';
```

You can even change the precision this way:

```
sprintf("%.1f",$time) // -> 0.0 seconds

sprintf("%.10f",$time) // -> 0.0000059605 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use number_format() 
Check http://php.net/number_format