# JSON_decode() acting weird, adding letters and renaming characters

Tags: json

I have an object `$code` which contains `[{"id":863183023486434}]`. After performing a decode, `$code = json_decode($code);`, the decoded `$code` returns`8.6318302348643E+14`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
    $a = '[{"id":863183023486434}]';
    $code = json_decode($a, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($code);exit();
?>
```

> OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: ya of course, If u put number and string both that time it's not working. As per above problem he/she work with number only so i'm given this type solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

`8.6318302348643E+14` is just [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for `863183023486434`. (Well, nearly; it's a bit truncated, probably because of IEEE-754 double-precision floating point precision issues.) You're seeing that because of how you're *outputting* the value, it's not that the value itself is different.

To output the number without scientific notation, [this answer says you use `sprintf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916675/display-float-value-w-o-scientific-notation) (I'm not a PHP guy).

Comment: i see! makes sense now. is there any way to _output_ the `$code` without rounding it off to its scientific notation?

Comment: @user3549132: Probably. I take it you're using PHP (the name `json_decode` suggests it)? I'm afraid I'm not a PHP expert.

Comment: yeah I am using PHP. alright. Im just gonna wait for somebody to point me at the right direction for this while I scan for my own.

Comment: A quick search for "php output number without scientific notation" turned up an answer for that here on SO, I've added it above.