# Converting scientific number read from excel into csv

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am having an issue while reading from the excel sheet. I am getting my barcode values in scientific format in csv.

How do i parse the original value instead of the scientific number ?

Example : 
9,96E+12 [In excel]

9960000000000 [I want this in CSV]

I am using fgetcsv function in php to parse the csv file.

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{
    if(!$header)
        $header = $row;
    else
        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```

Output that i am getting :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => FJT8-thr-thrtC2-VSXL
        [barcode] => 9960000000000
        [amount] => 70
        [status] => 1
    )
```

I want the output as

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => FJT8-thr-thrtC2-VSXL
        [barcode] => 9,96E+12
        [amount] => 70
        [status] => 1
    )
```

Comment: Are they all consistently in X,XXE+YY format?

Comment: this post might be helpful to review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916675/display-float-value-w-o-scientific-notation

Comment: @yanman1234 Cant reply on the user that uploads the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)  and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function to convert it back and forth as long as you convert the "," to "." before you use the number in PHP.

```
<?php

$start = '9,96E+12';
$str = floatval(str_replace(',','.',$start)); 

// Proof of concept
echo $start."<br />"; // starting off with 9,96E+12
echo $str."<br />"; // Converted number is 9960000000000
echo sprintf('%.2e',$str); // back to scientific number 9.96e+12


?>
```